# Kepp the middle relativelayout scrollable

Tags: android, android-layout

I have 3 relative layouts

```
---------------
layout1       |
---------------
layout2       |
---------------
layout3       |
```

In layout 2 I have a listview and I would like to make this layout fixed in size, such that when the listview item grows more, it will have its own scrollbar but doesn't push the 3rd relative layout down.

How can I set this up ?

Comment: So, you have a HEADER, A FOOTER and a ListView inbetween. Just make the 3 in another RealtiveLayout - The first one aligns to the Parent's Top, the 3rd to Parent's bottom and the listview below the 1st and above the 3rd...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the layout2 linear with a weight of 1 and then keep layout1 relative (alignTop) and layout3 relative (alignTop).

Should work.

Answer (score 0):

Like this

```
<LinearLayout
      android:orientation="vertical"
      ....>
      <RelativeLayout android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

      <RelativeLayout android:weight="1"/>

      <RelativeLayout android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</LinearLayout>
```